# virtualbox does not load AMD-V is disabled

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

VirtualBox was working fine until the last upgrades from Ubuntu 18.04. About a week ago.

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine manjaro.

```
AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: Did you check that it's not disabled in BIOS? It could've happened for various reasons *(e.g. firmware update, or just a BIOS glitch)*. If that didn't help, please add [an output from `sudo kvm-ok`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971516/2388257) to your question *(you need to install `cpu-checker` first)*.

Comment: Thanks Hi-Angel Missed that when I last looked. This worked!

Answer (score 3):

Per [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147270/virtualbox-does-not-load-amd-v-is-diabled?noredirect=1#comment1905692_1147270), the solution was to enable it in BIOS. How did it end up disabled after upgrade in the first place? Well, it could've been because of firmware upgrade, or even because of a BIOS glitch. I'm in particular have been dealing at work with a PC whose UEFI in obscure circumstances been disabling VT-x *(an Intel analog to AMD-V)*, so I had to manually enable it back.